# ¿Por que al imprimir las propiedades del objeto muestra Undefined?

Tags: javascript, poo, objeto, clase

estoy aprendiendo acerca de las clases y objetos en java script.
Cree una clase animal con especie, edad y color, y un objeto perro al cual le asigne especie perro, edad 5 y color cafe. Pero cuando trato de mostrar estas propiedades muestra `undefined` y no se porque:

```
class animal {
    construtor(especie,edad,color){
        this.especie = especie;
        this.edad = edad;
        this.color = color;
    }
}

let perro = new animal("perro",5,"cafe");

console.log(perro.color);
```

Answer (score 2):

Tienes mal la palabra "construtor", lo que debería de ser `constructor`.

Ya no te debería de dar problemas.

```js
class animal {
    constructor(especie,edad,color){
        this.especie = especie;
        this.edad = edad;
        this.color = color;
    }
}

let perro = new animal("perro",5,"cafe");

console.log(perro.color);
```

Comment: OMG, revise el codigo diez veces y no me di cuenta de eso jajaajja. muchas gracias

Comment: te debió de haber mostrado algún error en la sintaxis tal vez, sí estas usando VSCODE

Answer (score 0):

El **error** puntual que estas teniendo se debe a la **sintaxis** en la palabra *"constructor"*. Es decir, escribiste mal la palabra *"constructor"* poniendo en su lugar *"contructor"* :

El codigo arreglado seria el siguiente:

```
class animal {
    constructor(especie,edad,color){
        this.especie = especie;
        this.edad = edad;
        this.color = color;
    }
}

let perro = new animal("perro",5,"cafe");

console.log(perro.color);
```

Comment: revise el codigo diez veces y no me di cuenta de eso jajaajja. muchas gracias

Comment: Hubo media hora de diferencia entre esta y la otra respuesta. Por favor, en lugar de publicar respuestas similares vota a favor a las que ya existen.